# Numpy append not adding new row despite axis specification

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I'm new to numpy and I'm trying to create add a new row. I'm reading that I just need to specify the axis.

Right now I'm just testing

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(['1', '2', '3'])
print(np.append(arr, np.array(['4', '5', '6']), axis = 0))
```

but this always outputs ['1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6']. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: When dealing with multidimentional arrays you need to have the correct number of dimensions, i.e. `np.append(arr.reshape(1,-1), np.array([['4', '5', '6']]), axis = 0)`

Comment: Not an answer (and answer was already given). But since you said that you were new to numpy, it may be pertinent to know that `append` is usually a bad idea. There are some cases where that is the good thing to do (obviously; otherwise, it wouldn't even exist). But those cases are way less frequent than "new to numpy" people think. It is not at all like python lists, for which, appending or extending doesn't cost much. In numpy, it is always preferable to know in advance (when possible) the size of the array, and update only the content.

Comment: And when it is not possible, then, you should at least consider doing the `appending` work in pure python first, and then, only at the end, creating a numpy array with the whole data.

Comment: Quote `When axis is specified, values must have the correct shape`. `append` with axis is a direct call to `np.concatenate`.

Answer (score 6):

You array only has one dimension (axis), so you can't add your new data to another dimension. You first need to reshape:

```
out = np.append(arr[None], np.array([['4', '5', '6']]), axis=0)
```

Or:

```
out = np.append(arr.reshape(1, -1), np.array([['4', '5', '6']]), axis = 0)
```

That said, [`vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) might be better suited to your use-case:

```
out = np.vstack([arr, np.array(['4', '5', '6'])])
```

Output:

```
array([['1', '2', '3'],
       ['4', '5', '6']], dtype='<U1')
```